# Closing application (Acrobat, Word, Excel) after closing the last document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-word, acrobat

I have a few functions that generate Word, Excel or PDF documents. For example, the one I'm working on is exporting a report to a PDF file. After closing the report, it opens another PDF form created with LiveCycle ES 8.2 and it fills it with data from a database. After this, the document is closed, but for some reason, the instance of Acrobat is still open in foreground with no document opened.

Here is the code:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "myReport", acViewPreview
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, "C:\myReport.pdf", False
DoCmd.Close acReport, "myReport"

Dim gApp, avDoc, pdDoc, jso

Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.app")
Set avDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
If avDoc.Open(exprPDF, "") Then
    Set pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
    Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject

    '[...]

    pdDoc.Save PDSaveIncremental, FileNm 'Save changes to the PDF document
    pdDoc.Close 'Close the PDF document
End If

avDoc.Close (True)
Set gApp = Nothing
Set avDoc = Nothing
```

myReport never opens any instance of Acrobat. The line `avDoc.Open` does. I would like Acrobat to be closed when I do `avDoc.close`. Any ideas?

Comment: I notice 2 things that I would try...  `gApp.Close` and setting `gApp` to nothing after `avDoc`, so you're not trying to confuse things by having items opened/closed out of order

Comment: Sounds to me like you have unreasonable expectations. Normally closing a document shouldn't close the application that is displaying the document. Is there a `gApp.Quit` method or something simalar?

Comment: @SeanCheshire Already tried setting everything to nothing but it doesn't change much. As for gApp.Close and gApp.Quit, both methods exist and do nothing. My script fills the PDF form and then save it. It must be totally transparent to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more tests, I need to both close and quit all document objects to ensure that the app quits if there is no remaining opened document.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add:

```
gApp.Exit
```

before the

```
Set gApp = Nothing
```

That seems to do the tick, but the app is still there, hidden... To Actually kill Acrobat try this method here with "Acrobat.exe":
[How can I kill task manager processes through VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303173/how-can-i-kill-task-manager-processes-through-vba-code)
That method is a bit of a sledge hammer, but it works.

Comment: I honestly haven't worked in that project in years and I am not doing any VBA anymore nowadays but this could be useful for other developers with similar problems I guess.

Comment: I just actually tried the code, but it just seems to work. After changing and saving 50 documents Acrobat complains that the maximum number of documents it can open is reached, despite no document is visibly open and I see the Acrobat program appear and disappear in the task bar. I even added a 'gApp.CloseAllDocs' before the exit statement just to make sure... additionally to closing the AVDoc and the PDDoc.

Answer (score 0):

I have just experienced the same issue and found the following solution:

```
AVDoc.Close (True)
**AcroApp.Hide**

Set AcroApp = Nothing
Set AVDoc = Nothing
```