# How can I kill task manager processes through VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, process, taskmanager

I'm trying to kill certain processes through VBA. I have a proprietary object that connects to a market data bus. Through RTD I call this object to pub/sub to the bus. However sometimes the connection drops and I need to kill the process via task manager. Is there a way to kill a process through VBA?

Thanks

Comment: Which processes?  I did not downvote, but often these silent downvoters will do it because it's because you did not show your efforts so far(or explain why your google results are not helpful) to tackle the problem. It will help you and the next guy with the specific problem. Please [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 23):

Try with this code

```
Dim oServ As Object
Dim cProc As Variant
Dim oProc As Object

Set oServ = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

For Each oProc In cProc

    'Rename EXCEL.EXE in the line below with the process that you need to Terminate. 
    'NOTE: It is 'case sensitive

    If oProc.Name = "EXCEL.EXE" Then
      MsgBox "KILL"   ' used to display a message for testing pur
      oProc.Terminate()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: A little more straightforward, you can use: `Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'EXCEL.EXE'")` to only get Excel processes.

Comment: `errReturnCode Variable Not defined`

Comment: `oProc.Terminate` without brackets

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at one more example:

```
Sub Test()
    If TaskKill("notepad.exe") = 0 Then MsgBox "Terminated" Else MsgBox "Failed"
End Sub

Function TaskKill(sTaskName)
    TaskKill = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("taskkill /f /im " & sTaskName, 0, True)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform it, this way:

```
Dim oServ As Object
Dim cProc As Variant
Dim oProc As Object

Set oServ = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

For Each oProc In cProc

    'Rename EXCEL.EXE in the line below with the process that you need to Terminate. 
    'NOTE: It is 'case sensitive

    If oProc.Name = "EXCEL.EXE" Then
      MsgBox "KILL"   ' used to display a message for testing pur
      oProc.Terminate  'kill exe
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Kill_Excel()

Dim sKillExcel As String

sKillExcel = "TASKKILL /F /IM Excel.exe"
Shell sKillExcel, vbHide

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - to me, it looks like an answer that was already posted more than two years ago