# Excel application won't quit after checking in to sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I am having trouble quitting the excel application after checking in to sharepoint.  I have the following code in the thisworkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save

    If Workbooks.Count < 2 Then
        Application.Quit
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Close
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If ThisWorkbook.CanCheckIn Then
        ThisWorkbook.CheckIn
    Else
        MsgBox ("This workbook cannot be checked in.")
    End If
End Sub
```

The file is successful in checking in to sharepoint.  The workbook gets closed but the excel application is still running.  How do I terminate the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Quit
```

Should do the trick.  Add that when you want to close Excel.

Answer (score -1):

I've been having a similar problem and I found a quick discussion on what could be causing the Excel instance to not quit.

[Excel won't quit](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/vba/xl_doesnt_quit/)

And here is an absolutely awful way to get around having to properly code.

[How Can I Kill Task Manager Processes Through VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303173/how-can-i-kill-task-manager-processes-through-vba-code)

Comment: The url's need some sort of description.