# Excel Application.Quit doesn't kill the EXECL.EXE Process

Tags: excel, vbscript

I’ve identified some strange behaviour with Excel’s `Quit` command that I can’t find an explanation for or solution to.

The VBScript script below replicates the problem.  Here is what it does…

1. Creates a new Excel instance
2. Opens and closes a set number of workbooks (controlled by `WorkbooksToCreate`)
3. Attempts to `Quit` Excel
4. And then it proves whether Excel really did quit by changing the `Visible` state back to True

What I’ve gathered is that a successful `Quit` only occurs when `WorkbooksToCreate` is set to 0 or 1.  If set to 2 or higher, Excel won’t quit properly.

```
'Switch this between 1 and 2 to see the difference
'(1 = quit correctly, 2 = quit only changes the .visible to false)
Const WorkbooksToCreate = 2

'Create new Excel Instance
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

'Add, and then close workbooks
For w = 1 to WorkbooksToCreate
    Set WB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    WB.Close False
Next

'Attempt to Quit Excel
xlApp.Quit

'Test it really did quit
xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlApp = Nothing
```

I’m using Excel 2010 on Windows 7.

I’ve tried numerous variations on this, but can’t establish what the problem is.  Best I can tell is that all `xlApp.Quit` does, in this instance, is equivalent to `xlApp.Visible = False`

Interested to see if you of you guys have better luck, or if anyone has noticed similar behaviour with Excel?

Thanks

Comment: Does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26303330/4650297) help any?

Comment: I am curious if you put a small pause before the loop if it work. I wonder if the speed of create multiple workbooks hangs Excel in this instance.

Comment: @BruceWayne. I'm aware I could do it that way.  But more interested if anyone can explain why opening two workbooks is different to opening one or none.  Plus, without knowing the process id that method might close a different instance of excel than the one that was opened.  Thanks

Comment: @Scott yep, I tried a pause.  It didn't help.  I even paused it, and did the open and close by hand, before letting it skip to the quit. Still the same!

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue, regardless the value of `WorkbooksToCreate `, Windows 7 HB 64 bit, Excel 2010 64bit.

Comment: @omegastripes strange?  I'll try it on a different machine in the morning and report back.  Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Windows 7 with Excel 2013 32-bit

Comment: omegastripes @mikegrann I've tried it on my personal laptop and your right I can re-created it!  Must just be my work computer that's the problem.  I'll try it on another machine at work tomorrow.  I'm thinking it might be some addin?  So I'll try disabling them also.  I'll report back tomorrow.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to @omegastripes and @Mikegrann for identifying this doesn’t happen on every machine.

I’ve investigated further and found the found the issue is specific to my own work laptop.  The problem cannot be replicated on other machines.

But I have successfully traced and fixed the fault.  It was caused by one particular COM Add-In titled `CiscoClickToCall.Connect`.  Once this was uninstalled, then the script started behaving as expected, and did successfully quit.

I likely didn’t have to fully uninstall it from Windows; it would have been enough to just remove the Add-In from Excel, but it was an application I don’t have any use for so just I got rid of it.

From what I could tell all the Add-In was intended for was to add context menu commands to a cell’s right click.

Thanks for everyone’s help