# Application_startup and application_exit VBA

Tags: .net, vba, visual-studio, excel

I'm having a problem with closing an excel process I start up using the Application_Startup handler.

First I'll describe my program roughly:
Application.xaml.vb Application_startup reads an options file (and allows for changes if needed), then proceeds to load a gigantic excel file while the user is hit with a loading screen.

```
' Start Excel and get Application object.
XLapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XLapp.Visible = False
XLwb = XLapp.Workbooks.Open(HistoryPath, [ReadOnly]:=True)
```

When this is all done the MainWindow.xaml.vb shows up, where I use `My.Application.XLwb` to access the data. When I close MainWindow, a handler uses

```
Environment.Exit(0)
```

I had hoped this would fire the following sub in Application.xaml.vb:

```
Public Sub Application_Exit(sender As Object, e As ExitEventArgs) Handles Me.Exit
    Debug.Print("close")
    XLwb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
    XLapp.Application.Quit()
    Environment.Exit(0)
End Sub
```

However this does not work.
I've also tried the following:

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
    Try
        My.Application.XLapp.Application.Quit()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Environment.Exit(0)
End Sub
```

But the EXCEL.EXE process stays.

Any ideas on how to do this?

PS. For now I'm using [How can I kill task manager processes through VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303173/how-can-i-kill-task-manager-processes-through-vba-code) to remove the processes, but this removes them indiscriminately (i.e. some excel sheet someone was working on on the side will also get shut down)

Comment: `Environment.Exit(0)` is the very last thing you want to do here: that's a big huge red NUKE IT button akin to the `End` keyword in VBA - don't use that. Let your application exit through its `Main` procedure (i.e. let your "main form" close and return to its caller). Then `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` for every single COM object you're using - including the `Excel.Application`, any `Worksheet` object and `Worksheets` collection, `Range` - everything.

Comment: You'll have to stop using Environment.Exit().  On such a very large spreadsheet, there is a technical risk that you've created so many RCWs that a normal shutdown takes more than 2 seconds.  Which causes a finalizer thread abort and Excel will keep running.  That delay is noticeable, make sure you do not try to hide it.  If that is the case then you have to help by calling GC.Collect + GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers.  That takes as long as necessary, so probably more than 2 seconds, avoiding the finalizer thread abort.

Comment: @HansPassant is it a coincidence that calling `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on every single accessed COM object seems to work for me?

Comment: Yes, usually it does not work because you don't get every RCW.  And if you miss one then you can't find out which one it might be.  COM programming is supposed to be painful, but neither VB.NET nor C# make it painful enough.  Not a problem, the GC never gets it wrong.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thank you for the suggestion. I've removed any Environment.Exits but am now trying to figure out what the main forms caller is. I don't specifically call for the MainWindow, it just appears after the Application_Startup is done. I was thinking of putting the Marshal.ReleaseComObject in the Application_Exit handler but it does not ever fire. Currently the application just sits running (but essentially doing nothing) after MainWindow closes. Any ideas?