# Using VBA find and close hidden word applications

Tags: vba, ms-word

General Overview

I have a vba program build in excel whose purpose is to generate a pdf document. The way it goes about it, is that it populates a word ducment and then prints it as a pdf.

For ux reasons I have decided that the word application should not be visible to the user.

```
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = False
```

Issue

My problem comes from a day of working with the code. After running and exiting mid execution I have built up a number of hidden word application. ( Normal execution is not impacted by this because I set wdApp to null in the last lines of my code ).

How do I go about closing all these hidden word applications?

Edit:

After reading the comments to get me started I have adapted code to acomplish partly what I want.

```
Sub CloseWordFile_If_Open_And_Not_Visible()

Dim wdApp As Object

On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wdApp Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do While wdApp.Visible = False

        wdApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

        On Error Resume Next
        Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0

        If wdApp Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

The only issue with this code is that if it sees an instance of word which is .visible = true then it stops and exits without closing any subsequent word application (where .visible = false).

Is there a way to skip this instance of word and register another word application so that GetObject(, "Word.Application") return a different application?

Comment: What is the reason of mid execution exiting? If there are some errors - add error handling which will quit word app. Anyway you may resort to force closing by [terminating all word processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26303173/2165759), or (more gentle) make VBA loop through each running word app instance returned by `GetObject()`, check `.Visible` state and `.Quit` if hidden.

Comment: Me working in the code. ( Run Code till break - See issue - Fix issue which causes the execution to stop ). Thank you for the suggestion of GetObject()

Comment: If the cause of the "breaking" is because you're altering the code, then simply make the Word application visible while you're doing that.

Comment: @omegastripes I have some doubts whether GetObject() will pick up all these instances of Word, have you tested that? I never have. But the way I understand GetObject it queries the ROT, and Word will register only *one* instance of itself in the ROT. This is well-documented and is leveraged in order to be able to run instances of Word that the user won't pick up when working in-parallel with a program automating Word. But I could be wrong...

Comment: Simply start the Task Manager and manually kill off any Word sessions running in the background. While doing code development, it's best to keep automated applications (and files) visible, so you're not left with orphaned sessions in the background the event of a crash.

Comment: In production a requirement is that the user doesn't see the word document. Low level security to prevent users from just modifying the word document and generating a new pdf. So I need to keep them hidden and I can't just close all the winword.exe in the taskmanger b/c I don't want to close a document that the end user was working on not related to my code.