# How to stop the running task that has been created using ShellExecute Command in VBA

Tags: vba

How to stop running application that has been executed using ShellExecute command in VB

I have tried with objShell. Quit, objShell. Kill but not satisfied. Error of ActiveX Automation: no such property or method is thrown

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute C:\Users\xyz.exe, "", ""
objShell.Kill
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I kill task manager processes through VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303173/how-can-i-kill-task-manager-processes-through-vba-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is only opening the application, but not keeping any control of it.

One way of achieving more control is this:

```vb
Sub terminate()

Dim exeID As Double
exeID = Shell("C:\Users\xyz.exe", vbNormalFocus)
Call Shell("TaskKill /F /PID " & exeID, vbHide)

End Sub
```