# Quitting Excel Workbook from Word leaves Excel open

Tags: vba, ms-word, excel-2010

I have a Macro in Word, that is reading data from an Excel file. 
I have the following lines in my Macro to open and close the Excel file:

```
Excel_path = "C:\Users\....\Documents\myExcelfile.xlsx"
Dim myExcel As Object
Dim myWB As Object
Set myExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWB = myExcel.Workbooks.Open(Excel_path)
With myWB.Sheets(2)
    *.... Reading in data ....*
End With

myWB.Close savechanges:=False
myExcel.Quit
End Sub
```

Although I close both the workbook and I quit the application, I keep getting the message that my Excel file is locked for editing after succesfully running the Macro in Word. Also, if I close the Word application I keep having this..
I checked in my Excel workbook, but it doesn't show any connections. 
How can I truly quit my Excel workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would Suggest you to do :

```
Application.Quit
```

For example :

```
myWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

With myExcel
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Quit
End With
```

And if after that Excel process Still exist in your process manager then use `kill` to kill excel process. You can found [an example there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26303330/11167163).

Basicly I would do like this to be sure that Excel Is definitivly closed :

```
Sub Tryme()

Dim MyList As Object
Dim oServ As Object
Dim cProc As Variant
Dim oProc As Object

myWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

With myExcel
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Quit
End With

Set objList = GetObject("winmgmts:") _
    .ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='" & process & "'")

If MyList.Count > 0 Then
  Set oServ = GetObject("winmgmts:")
  Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
  For Each oProc In cProc
      If oProc.Name = "EXCEL.EXE" Then
         MsgBox "KILL"   ' used to display a message for testing pur
         oProc.Terminate()
      End If
  Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That will close the host application instead, in this case, MS-Word.

Comment: Application in this context refers to Word. To refer to Excel `myExcel.Application.Quit` which is the same as `myExcel.Quit`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't close the workbook, instead do:

```
myWB.Saved = True
myExcel.Quit
```

Instead of setting .Saved you can also set

```
myWB.DisplayAlerts = False
```