# How to terminate a running program with VBA?

Tags: vba

Im trying to tweek some VBA code to terminate a program on my computer.

But what am i doing wrong :)

```
    Sub Kill_SAP()

Dim oServ As Object
Dim cProc As Variant
Dim oProc As Object

Set oServ = GetObject("winmgmts:")

Set procs = oServ.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process where name = 'saplogon.exe'")
    For Each oProc In cProc
    
        If oProc.Name = "saplogon.exe" Then
          'MsgBox "KILL"   ' used to display a message for testing pur
          oProc.Terminate  'kill
        End If
    Next



End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/26303330/17172829, i guess you miss the query.

Comment: Try    `Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process where name = 'saplogon.exe'")`

Comment: I get Run-time error '424' Objekt required From the same point, "for each oProc In cProc"
Funthomas

Comment: I added your row funthomas

Comment: No one? I’m still stuck. I guess this is a simple thing for you gurus :)

Comment: Typo? You have `Set procs = ...` but then `For Each oProc In cProc ...`

Comment: Yup i've seen that, but thought it was some kind of "variable"  :)

its from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74138319/how-to-terminate-a-running-program-with-vba

I changed , but same issue.

Comment: No one else? Strange problem.

Comment: Anyone knows how to terminate a program?